# jest/enzyme testing using theme prop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, styled-components

When I test a component that uses theme props in its styles, the theme props render in the test correctly, but the tests fail.

Using this test:

```
import theme from './theme.js';

it('should display on mobile ', () => {
    wrapper = renderer.create(<HamburgerIcon theme={theme} />).toJSON();
    expect(wrapper).toHaveStyleRule('display', 'flex', { media: `(max-width:${theme.mobile})` });
});
```

I get this error:

> **No style rules found on passed Component using options:
>       {"media":"(max-width:500px)"}**

So, it seems to be converting `(max-width:${theme.mobile})` to the correct px value, but it's not matching any styles to that value.

If I change the media query in the styled-component to `@media (max-width: 500px)`, and then I test for it, like this:

```
it('should display on mobile ', () => {
    wrapper = renderer.create(<HamburgerIcon theme={theme} />).toJSON();
    expect(wrapper).toHaveStyleRule('display', 'flex', { media: '(max-width: 500px)' });
});
```

then the test passes.

Given that I'm using theme props for a number of different style attributes, I want to be able to use the theme props in the testing. Is there a way to to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: what's in `theme.mobile`? `500` or `500px`?

Comment: Theme.mobile is 500px

Comment: Is it just the space in '(max-width:␠500px)'? Maybe it requires an exact match.